Is there a way to run a snakemake rule remotely (e.g. on Google Batch) if one or more of its inputs are flagged as local?
I have a snakemake pipeline that I want to run all remotely, but some of the input files are from the local host system. When I try to run the pipeline, any rule with a local input file flagged with local('filename') runs locally on the host machine. In addition to it running locally, it doesn't use the conda environment provided.
I have tried running the rules and having 'localrule: False' in the rule but that does not work. There may be an easy setting that I just missed in the documentation. Any help would be appreciated.
It looks like this pull request is the reason it infers the local job but I am unsure how to get around that: https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/pull/2541
This is the current command I am using to run the pipeline.
snakemake --executor googlebatch --googlebatch-project <project> --googlebatch-region <region> --default-storage-provider gcs --default-storage-prefix gcs://<bucket/subdir> --storage-gcs-project <project> --jobs 8 --sdm conda --use-conda --latency-wait 30
